# How to create Class dynamically in a proper way in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to migrate my app to typescript. I have kind of a base class that is my base library object. My classes created dependent on the base class. Below is a glimpse of my problem.

Below code works but autocomplete doesn't work. Couldn't figure out what should be defined for the type of `Model`.

```js
const map = new WeakMap();
function weakRef<T>(context: T): T {
  // @ts-ignore
  if (!map.has(context)) { map.set(context, {}); }
  // @ts-ignore
  return map.get(context);
}
function getModel(provider: Provider) {
  return class Model {
    getSomething(key: string) {
      return weakRef(provider).configuration(key);
    }
  };
}

class Provider {
  configuration: (key: string) => string;
  constructor() {
    weakRef(this).configuration = (key: string) => {
      return key;
    };
    weakRef(this).Model = getModel(this);
  }
  get Model(): any {
    return weakRef(this).Model;
  }
  set Model(model: any) {
    weakRef(this).Model = model;
  }
}

const provider = new Provider();
const obj = new (provider.Model)();
console.log(obj.getSomething('test')); // This works, but autocomplete doesn't
```

I don't want to pass provider to the constructor in base model.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the return type of a function type with `ReturnType<T>`.

In this case, `ReturnType<typeof getModel>` should do the trick.

You can also fix the `//@ts-ignore` lines by constraining `T` to be an object type.

```
const map = new WeakMap();
function weakRef<T extends object>(context: T): T {
  if (!map.has(context)) { map.set(context, {}); }
  return map.get(context);
}
```

That said, I think this architecture is unnecessarily complicated. Why not just use `this` instead of a value tied to `this`?

Comment: Thanks it works. To answer your question, main reason is to make memory optimized library. you can look weakmap or weakset for more information.

Comment: @trd3v3lop that would make sense if multiple instances were sharing the same data... but they aren't, at least in your example. It is useless overhead.